# IE dropping "%" from dimensions when appending html string

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, height, width

I'm attempting to create a video element as a string, set the height and width from variables (also strings), and I'm finding that IE9 is dropping the "%" from the dimension values. Here's a boiled-down example:

html:

```
<div id="videoWrap">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var height = '100%',
    width = '100%',
    video = '<video id="someId" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' +
            '<source src="http://someSource.com" /></video>';

$('#videoWrap').append(video);
```

result in Chrome (or any other reasonable browser):

```
<div id="videoWrap">
    <video id="someId" width="100%" height="100%">
        <source src="http://someSource.com" />
    </video>
</div>
```

result in IE:

```
<div id="videoWrap">
    <video id="someId" width="100" height="100">
        <source src="http://someSource.com" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`width` and `height` are NOT how you should be styling an element for size. Those two attributes are supposed to indicate a size in pixels ONLY.

Instead, do it properly with `style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because IE is stricter about the standard in this case.

According to [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-map-element.html#attr-dim-width), the dimensions have to specificed as integer values as pixels. Using percent is not valid.

Comment: In other words, IE is the "reasonable browser" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to do the following:

```
var vdo = $('<video/>').css({'width':'100%','height':'100%'});
```

and then add your rest...